# GET Request using fetch + application/x-ndjson

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, fetch-api

Currently trying to issue a GET request to my Elasticsearch index using the _msearch API.

I have no idea how to write the `fetch` request when using `application/x-ndjson`

```
const msearch = await fetch(
        `${ELASTIC_NODE}/${ELASTIC_INDEX}/_msearch`,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Basic ${ELASTIC_TOKEN}`,
                'content-type': 'application/x-ndjson',
            },
            body: `{}\n{ "query":{"match_all": {}}}\n`
        },
    ).catch(err => {
        console.log('found an error', JSON.stringify(err));
        return { err, error: true }
    })
```

Emphasis on the body part. What I've tried

`body: {}\n{ "query":{"match_all": {}}}\n`

`body: [ {}, { "query":{"match_all": {}}}]`

And with combinations of JSON.stringify.

How do I properly craft the body?

Comment: What is wrong with the current code? Do you get an error?

Comment: My error message is non-existent, just a blanket "error" sadly

Comment: What kind of error? What's the status code of the response?

Comment: 500 internal server, the catch statement console log is just "found an error, error"

Comment: Request bodies on `GET` requests are super flaky and shouldn't be relied on. I believe elasticsearch does offer alternative APIs. I can really recommend *not* doing this.

Comment: It definitely works as just curl. The issue is not elastic per se, it's how do I write the syntax for a fetch request?

Comment: If it works with CURL it doesn't mean your browser will do this.

Comment: Try switching to a POST request?

Comment: It worked with a POST request! Unreal

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it now:

```
body: JSON.stringify(
                `{}\n
            { "query":{"match_all": {}}}\n
            `
            )
```

Comment: Why does this help? This will output `"\"{}\\n\\n            { \\\"query\\\":{\\\"match_all\\\": {}}}\\n\\n            \""` --- when using template literals, `\n` is not needed.

Comment: Hmm, looks like a false positive. Care to share an answer? :)

Comment: Do you have a way to validate ndjson?